# Can't create or copy folders in the web root folder of Apache on mac

Tags: macos, mac, apache-http-server

I am always asked to provide my password whenever I try to create a new folder or copy anything into the root folder of apache which is located at "/Library/WebServer/Documents/".

I am just switching from Windows and IIS so I am totally new to the world of Mac and Apache, when I was trying to find the location of the root folder of apache I found that there are 2 root folders one at the system level which can be accessed by localhost and one at the user level which can be accessed by localhost/~username. I want to work with the system level option because I am the only user on my mac and no one else is going to use it and I don't want to be asked for the password whenever I try to do anything in the root folder.

How can I change this behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write there because the directory doesn't belong to you.

So you can give write access to everybody (not recommended) or add access for your account.

From the finder menu "File > Get Info". At the bottom of the information window, in the sharing & permissions section, you can add read/write acces for yourself (You will have to unlock the lock first).

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behavior with

```
chmod o+rw /Library/WebServer/Documents
```

<sub>(This allows any user to write to the directory)</sub>

But this is not recommended. This reduces the security of the system, and makes it easier for someone to break into your system and use the webserver to launch an attack unless whatever you're doing with the web server is perfectly secure.

Comment: If this is not recommended and I decided not to do it so I'll have to get myself used to always providing the password! Is there any other solution other than this?

Comment: I don't understand why I am being asked for the password?